# Jquery AJAX post to update database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the following code in my HTML form - trying to make a sort of "lottery scratch ticket" type effect.  There's a grid, each item with a dynamic number from a database.  Clicking the square calls the clickme() function, makes the db call, and then changes the image.  I'm just on the first part trying to get the database to update.

My PHP/HTML:

```
    if ($unlock == 0) { 
    echo '<div> class="' . $currentgrid .'" name="' . $slot . '"   
    onclick="clickme();" style="cursor: pointer;">'; 
    } else { echo '<div>'; }
```

And my javascript.js file:

```
function clickme()
{
// $(function() {
//    $(".gridsquare").click(function() {

    var slotnumber = $(this).attr('name');
    // var gridnumber = $(this).attr('class');
    var dataString = 'slot='+ slotnumber;
    // + '&gridnumber=' + gridnumber;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post/supergridupdate.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                // $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                // $('.error').fadeout(400).hide;
            }
        });

    return false;
//    });
// });

}
```

supergridupdate.php:

```
    <?php 
     $slot = $_POST['slot']; 
     // $gridnumber = $_POST['gridnumber']; 
     $gridnumber = 1;
     $sql = "INSERT INTO test (slot, gridnumber) VALUES ('$slot', '$gridnumber')";
     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
     ?>
```

Right now it all displays, I can click divs but the database doesn't update.

UPDATE:  Got it to work with help, just simply passing the variable in the javascript function now instead of using jquery.

Comment: What about the source for `post/supergridupdate.php` ?  Also, in your HTML, you need to remove the `>` from `echo '<div> class = ...`

Comment: Looks good to me. The file you're posting to needs to take it from here. `$_POST['slot']` is the variable you'll be using from that context.

Comment: Cool thx on the <div> - was a typo when i was trying to get the code to display correctly in my post above :)

Comment: I saw a mini error - updated my supergridupdate.php above in the post - I wasn't passing the gridnumber variable in my AJAX, which is fine, i can deal with that later, but still not working with just trying to update with one variable.

Comment: @916 Networks: you can answer your own question so that others can benefit from it

Comment: Oh - the mini error that I fixed didn't fix it... :(

Comment: After some troubleshooting - it appears my variable is not getting passed correctly. I added the code alert("slot is "+ slotnumber); after the variable slotnumber is grabbed using jquery, and the slotnumber variable is blank.  I've confirmed my name= in my HTML gives the dynamic number (ex. name=31)

Comment: sry i thought you have solved the problem ...

Comment: console.log("this", this) in firebug to see what "this" is. also you don't need to get a jQuery object to get the name attribute. You can just do this.name when you get that part straightened out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that 'slotnumber' has a value? Also have you tried sending an object rather than a string? `var dataString = {'slot': slotnumber};`
--EDIT
in your function try to pass the element to the function `onclick="clickme(this);"`

```
function clickme(el)
{
// $(function() {
//    $(".gridsquare").click(function() {

    var slotnumber = $(el).attr('name');
    // var gridnumber = $(this).attr('class');
```

Comment: Thanks - no, the var slotnumber is not getting a value.  Thought the jquery (this).attr('name'); would give me the value of the name= in my HTML (example, first div has name=1 attribute, next div has name=2 attribute)

Comment: So for the edit, I want to pass onclick="clickme(3)" or whatever the slotvalue should be?  and then use the code for the function clickme(el)?

Comment: That would work too rather than relying upon the name attribute then the clickme function would be clickme(slotnumber) and then don't forget to remove the code that defines slotnumber in the function

Comment: Nice, that did work.  Thanks.  I'll update my code to show what worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have commented `// $gridnumber = $_POST['gridnumber'];` 
and you are using it in query not sure if thats causing error.

Add this

```
success: function(data){
 alert(data);
}
```

Can you do echo $result or Exception and see if it throws any error ? Also do echo $sql which will alert the query . That way you can see what exactly happened.

Also wrap query execution in try catch to be safe

```
try{

   $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: cool thanks, got the update part to work, now just trying to get the slotnumber var to populate in the script

Answer (score 0):

Just like that, are you connected to your database on that file "supergridupdate.php" ?

Comment: Thanks - got the database update part going. Now need to find out why my slot value is not passing, it's zero in the update (and the alert)

Answer (score 0):

i hope prior to making update in the `db` you have correctly established the connection

in your supergridupdate.php you are doing

```
$slot = $_POST['slot'];
```

so in your ajax request you need to do

```
data:{slot:dataString},
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are generating the html correctly or is it just a typo. You are closing the div tag before attributes. Try this

`echo '<div class="' . $currentgrid .'" name="' . $slot . '" onclick="clickme();" style="cursor: pointer;">';`

Comment: Yea, HTML ok - but my jquery not working right.  Straight javascript did it.  Thanks for checking it though.