# Update PHP variable from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I retrieve the price for an item in my MySQL database like following:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT 'price' FROM 'items'");
$price = $result;
```

I echo this `$price` variable on the page. However, since you can bid on the item, you need to know what the price is the second you bid on it. Therefore I need to be able to update the price for the item (any new bids are stored in the same database, overwriting the old entry).

How do I regularly update the `$price` variable from my database *without* updating the entire page?

Edit: To clarify: I'm not looking for a function to update my MySQL database, I'm looking for a function that will allow me to draw a new MySQL query without updating the document.

Comment: use backtickes instead of single quotes $result = mysqli_query("SELECT `price` FROM `items`"); by jquery - ajax u can update your tables without page refresh [here an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738888/jquery-ajax-post-to-update-database) on how to use ajax

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the field using jQuery. In your #price div use jQuery ajax get and update that div in every second.

Answer (score 0):

This might help Use jQuery and PHP to build an Ajax-driven Web page
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following html...

```
<div id="price"></div>
New Bid Amount <input type="text" id="bid" /> 
<button id="updatePrice">Update</button>
```

You are probably going to want to post the new bid amount to save it so the following would work to post to a file called update-bid.php

```
<script>
    $("#updatePrice").click(function() {
        bid = $('#bid').val();
        $.post("update-bid.php", { bid: bid }, function(req) {
            if ($.trim(req) == 'success') $('#price').html(bid);
        });
    });
</script>
```